# Path of the photo album from iphone device

Tags: iphone, ipad, image-processing, filepath

In my project, i want to do something like this.
I just want to read the Path of the photo albums from the iPhone device,from where i want to get the photos. After getting the photos, i want to display the photos as views with swiping methodology, similar in the photo albums but in my project.

Is there is a way to achieve this?
Please advice me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not directly access the photo library from what I am aware of, but you can always use the image picker, which seems to have your required functionality.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070